# How to apply .asp web application to phonegap

Tags: ios4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having Web application using .aspx now i want to develop same application for iPad so can i used PhoneGap API for development.If it is possible then can any buddy provide me the documentation or step by step process for how to do this.
If any one having sample demo for same then please help me.

My web application is like news portal (like, Times of india for ipad version) so i want to make it for ipad.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp is server side scripting language, it doesn't have much to do with phonegap or ipad apps.

To develop an ipad application using phonegap you will need to write your application in client technologies like html, css and javascript. In the same way a website is written. 
Then you can use phonegap to wrap your web-app. This will enable you to distribute it in the various app stores.

You can off-cause use asp to serve data to you app.

Go [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/phonegap-mobile-app-pt1.html) to learn more about phonegap